# Badge progress indicator missing number counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, badge-progress

Something changed recently, and since a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: badge progress]

Until not very long ago, the "score" and "answers" labels were followed by numbers indicating the values of the progress bars underneath. So "score" might have "90/100" in this example. I'm not seeing that now for any of the badge progress indicators, so it looks like a recently introduced bug.

Comment: meta-meta-question: shouldn't `badge-tracking` be a synonym of `badge-progress`?

Comment: FWIW, the image comes from StackOverflow, and I have 20K+ rep there. The issue is that the numbers next to "score" and "answer" have gone missing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Maybe, I just wen't with [meta-tag:badge-tracking] because it says it's for the profile page right in the description.

Comment: @Caleb maybe only Jon Skeet gets to see the numbers. ;-(

Comment: @Caleb - I slightly edited the title to convey the issue of the numbers missing so that it is a little more direct. At first it seemed like you were addressing a different issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was my bad when fixing some localization issues.

A fix will be pushed out shortly.

Comment: Great -- thanks Jarrod!

Comment: Localization. It's always localization. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard either that or caching ;)

Comment: @ChrisF caching is so 2014... localization is the new thing to blame. :D

Comment: **Confirmed!** Happy to see the numbers back where they belong.